# PHP Prophecy Mystery

Tags: php, phpunit, prophecy

I have `$entity_type->isSubClassOf('Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityInterface')->willReturn(TRUE);` and getting this very baffling error:

```
Prophecy\Exception\Call\UnexpectedCallException: Method call:
  - isSubclassOf("Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityInterface")
on Double\EntityTypeInterface\P121 was not expected, expected calls were:
  - isSubClassOf(exact("Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityInterface"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful readers will observe the lower case c vs upper case c after `isSub`. I posted the problem to https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy/issues/249